# Parsing through elements in json type format in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data frame with geoid that looks like this

[image]

What I want to do is get each geoid number for each msaid into a list. Ideally I would like to have is a dataframe that looks something like this

[image]

I hope that makes sense. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is two examples:

```
159 [{"geoid":"02020000101"},{"geoid":"02020000204"},{"geoid":"02020000300"},{"geoid":"02020000400"},{"geoid":"02020000500"},{"geoid":"02020000600"},{"geoid":"02020000802"},{"geoid":"02020000901"},{"geoid":"02020000902"},{"geoid":"02020001000"},{"geoid":"02020001500"},{"geoid":"02020001601"},{"geoid":"02020001602"},{"geoid":"02020001701"},{"geoid":"02020001802"},{"geoid":"02020001900"},{"geoid":"02020002000"},{"geoid":"02020002100"},{"geoid":"02020002201"},{"geoid":"02020002400"},{"geoid":"02020002501"},{"geoid":"02020002502"},{"geoid":"02020002601"},{"geoid":"02020002712"},{"geoid":"02020002811"},{"geoid":"02020002812"},{"geoid":"02020002813"},{"geoid":"02122000100"},{"geoid":"02122000300"},{"geoid":"02170001300"},{"geoid":"02170000300"},{"geoid":"02170001100"},{"geoid":"02170000800"},{"geoid":"02261000300"},{"geoid":"02290000400"},{"geoid":"02240000400"},{"geoid":"02170000102"},{"geoid":"02170000402"},{"geoid":"02170000101"},{"geoid":"02170001201"},{"geoid":"02170001001"},{"geoid":"02170000706"},{"geoid":"02170001202"},{"geoid":"02170001004"},{"geoid":"02170000705"},{"geoid":"02170000603"},{"geoid":"02020000102"},{"geoid":"02020000201"},{"geoid":"02020000202"},{"geoid":"02020000203"},{"geoid":"02020000701"},{"geoid":"02020000702"},{"geoid":"02020000703"},{"geoid":"02020000801"},{"geoid":"02020001100"},{"geoid":"02020001200"},{"geoid":"02020001300"},{"geoid":"02020001400"},{"geoid":"02020001702"},{"geoid":"02020001731"},{"geoid":"02020001732"},{"geoid":"02020001801"},{"geoid":"02020002202"},{"geoid":"02020002301"},{"geoid":"02020002302"},{"geoid":"02020002303"},{"geoid":"02020002602"},{"geoid":"02020002603"},{"geoid":"02020002702"},{"geoid":"02020002711"},{"geoid":"02020002821"},{"geoid":"02020002822"},{"geoid":"02020002823"},{"geoid":"02020002900"},{"geoid":"02068000100"},{"geoid":"02170000200"},{"geoid":"02170000900"},{"geoid":"02261000100"},{"geoid":"02170000401"},{"geoid":"02170000502"},{"geoid":"02170000501"},{"geoid":"02170000604"},{"geoid":"02170000601"},{"geoid":"02170001003"},{"geoid":"02170000703"},{"geoid":"02170000701"}]
```

Comment: Post sample data as text

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: You can use apply in combination with explode.

Comment: @bigbounty I posted a text example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the file and saved it in my computer as a csv file. Then I ran the following code.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('parse_this.csv')
#remove characters and convert to list
df.tracts = df.tracts.apply(lambda x: x.strip('][').split(','))
#explode tracts series
df = df.explode('tracts')
#resetting index and renaming columns
df.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)
df.rename(columns={"tracts": "geoid"} , inplace = True)
#removing extra characters to keep only the geoid number
df.geoid = df.geoid.apply(lambda x: x.strip('geoid{}:""'))
df
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this example helps:

```
#creating a dataframe for example:

d = [{'A':3,'B':[{'id':'001'},{'id':'002'}]},
    {'A':4,'B':[{'id':'003'},{'id':'004'}]},
    {'A':5,'B':[{'id':'005'},{'id':'006'}]},
    {'A':6,'B':[{'id':'007'},{'id':'008'}]}]
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df
    A   B
0   3   [{'id': '001'}, {'id': '002'}]
1   4   [{'id': '003'}, {'id': '004'}]
2   5   [{'id': '005'}, {'id': '006'}]
3   6   [{'id': '007'}, {'id': '008'}]

#apply an explode to the column B and reset index

df = df.explode('B')
df.reset_index(drop = True, inplace = True)
df

# now it looks like this
    A    B
0   3   {'id': '001'}
1   3   {'id': '002'}
2   4   {'id': '003'}
3   4   {'id': '004'}
4   5   {'id': '005'}
5   5   {'id': '006'}
6   6   {'id': '007'}
7   6   {'id': '008'}

# now we need to remove the extra text and rename the column from B to id
df.B = df.B.apply(lambda x: x['id'])
df.rename(columns={"B": "id"} , inplace = True)

# this is the final product:
df
    A   id
0   3   001
1   3   002
2   4   003
3   4   004
4   5   005
5   5   006
6   6   007
7   6   008
```

Comment: I tried this approach with what you did but it did not change anything to the original dataframe

Comment: In my code I am leaving df as is and applying any changes to another dataframe (df1). I always like to leave the original df as is in case I need to go back. You will see the updates in df1.

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx I updated the code to remove the df1 and left all the code with df only. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Made a new question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63178154/attempting-to-use-explode-in-pandas-dataframe-results-in-no-change-to-the-data?noredirect=1#63178507

Comment: I downloaded the data and it seems like tracts is a string, which will make it fail because explode is looking for a list type.

Comment: Yea on the new post I made there are ways to resolve it but I am getting this SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal